# Retrofit returns null When My API reply 404

Tags: java, android, parsing, gson, retrofit2

I have an API. It returns 404 when it does not data in Database. Retrofit 2 returns null response when my API returns 404 as response code.

Barcode.activity:

```
LnkBarcodeBaptizeCheckModel lnkModel = new LnkBarcodeBaptizeCheckModel();
                        List<String> bap_barcodes = new ArrayList<String>();
                        bap_barcodes.add(barcode);
                        lnkModel.bap_barcodes = bap_barcodes;Call<LnkBarcodeBaptizeCheckResponseModel> lnkCall = apiInterface.CheckLnkBarcodeBaptizeTable(lnkModel);
                        LnkBarcodeBaptizeCheckResponseModel lnkResponse = new MainAynscTask<LnkBarcodeBaptizeCheckResponseModel>().execute(lnkCall).get();
```

Client:

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localserver/IndustrialApplicationsAPI/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();



    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Post method:

```
@POST("CuringPhase/CheckLnkBarcodeBaptizeTable")
Call<LnkBarcodeBaptizeCheckResponseModel> CheckLnkBarcodeBaptizeTable(@Body LnkBarcodeBaptizeCheckModel trcModel);
```

Retrofit Call:

```
public class MainAynscTask<T> extends AsyncTask<Call<T>, Void, T> {

@Override
protected T doInBackground(Call<T>... call) {
    T responseModel = null;
    try {
        responseModel = call[0].execute().body();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Call error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return responseModel;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(T result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //how i will pass this result where i called this task?
}
```

}

Actually, I get response but It does not parsing.

{"responseCode":404,"data":[],"error":{"errorCode":404,"errorDesc":"Not found!"}}
<-- END HTTP (81-byte body)

```
API Response:
{
  "responseCode": 404,
  "data": [

  ],
  "error": {
    "errorCode": 404,
    "errorDesc": "Not found!"
  }
}
```

What is the reason?

By the way, It parses the response when I just change the response code to 200.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response code 404 means that app was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. Might I suggest that you take a look at your api request parameters and how is the backend handling those requests

**Edited:**

You can parse your error response(if you are sending one) by using JSONObject

```
JSONObject erroObj = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());

// or if you have an custom error model class then do this
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<YourErrorResponseClass>() {}.getType();
YourErrorResponseClass errorResponse = 
gson.fromJson(response.errorBody(),type);
```

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: I developt that API. When API cannot find data in Database, It response 404. I would like to parse response of API. But as I understand Retrofit automatically returns null when it encounter response code is 404. Beacuse, when I change the response code to 200 even if API cannot find any data in Database.